# Monomorphisms vs pullbacks

Tags: category-theory

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism in a category.
It is easy to see that if $f$ is a monomorphism then there exists a pullback $X \times_Y X$.

Here the question is whether the converse is true.

If two projections of $X\times_Y X$ equal then it is easy to check.

So my question is rewritten as whether the two projections equal always.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you mean to ask, "if $X \times_Y X$ exists and the two projections $X \times_Y X \to X$ are equal, then $X \to Y$ is a monomorphism"?

Comment: No. It is easy. I want it without assumption of equal projection.

Comment: I want:If $X \times_Y X$ exists for morphism $f:X\to Y$ then $f$ is a monomorphism.

Comment: That's false in general.

Comment: Thank you. It means that Prof Vakil page29 was wrong. Could you give me a reason or some reference?

Comment: No. He is right. I misunderstood what he means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **Set**, the pullback $X \times_Y X$ always exists and is given by
$$\left\{ (x,x') \in X \times X \, \mid\, f(x) = f(x') \right\},$$
regardless of whether $f$ is a monomorphism or not.

Answer (score 4):

The correct statement is that $f$ is a monomorphism if and only if the pullback $X \times_Y X$ not only exists but is naturally isomorphic to $X$.

Comment: "Naturally" here means that the two projections are equal and are isomorphisms.