If we have two cofiltered systems with injective maps between them, is the induced map on the cofiltered limit also an injection?
I have a system of $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces $(V_{i, j})_{(i, j) \in I \times J}$, where $I$ is cofiltered and $J$ is filtered. For each fixed $j \in J$, let
$$
W_j = \underset{\substack{\leftarrow \\ i}}{\operatorname{lim}} V_{i, j}
$$
Now, I additionally know that for each fixed $i \in I$, the map $V_{i,j_1} \to V_{i,j_2}$ is an injection.
Does it necessarily follow that all the induced maps $W_{j_1} \to W_{j_2}$ are also injections? In particular, I would like to write
$$
X = \bigcup_j W_j
$$
instead of
$$
X = \underset{\substack{\rightarrow \\ j}}{\operatorname{lim}} W_j
$$
but I'm not sure whether it makes sense to use the union symbol here, as I'm not sure whether the induced maps are actually injections.

I assume $j_1 \leq j_2$ are fixed indices? Then you don't need $J$ at all. Your question is just about cofiltered limits (in one variable) resp. their functoriality.

@MartinBrandenburg Yes, that was just the setup that I encountered. You're right, I could have simplified it like that.

Sure. Limits of monomorphisms are monomorphisms, since limits commute with limits, but you can also prove this directly just by using the definitions.

Can you elaborate on how being a monomorphism is a limit?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217966/monomorphisms-vs-pullbacks

Sorry, I can't quite piece this together. So $f: X \to Y$ is a monomorphism iff the diagram $$\begin{array}{*5c}&&\operatorname{id}&&\&X&\rightarrow&X&\\operatorname{id}&\downarrow&&\downarrow&f\&X&\rightarrow&Y&\&&f&&\\end{array}$$ is a pullback diagram.

So now if $(X_i)$ and $(Y_i)$ are two diagrams with monomorphisms $\varphi: X_i \to Y_i$, by commutativity of limits we get that the above square is also a pullback of the inverse limits, hence $\varphi$ is a monomorphism? Is that correct?

Yes that is correct.
